# What is the meaning of this conversation between Dewey Finn & Billy?

Tags: dialogue, school-of-rock

In *[School Of Rock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0332379/)* (2003) there's this conversation between Dewey Finn and Billy:

> Dewey: Billy, how's beautification?
>
> Billy: Are you kidding?

What is the meaning of this conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Billy's response is as such due to his outrage that he's even being asked for progress, after being tasked with what he might consider a near-impossible share of the work. This, plus his obviously dramatic attitude led him to express his outrage in this way.

He created one set of suggestions for Freddy and Katie, but they didn't seem to enjoy the glam-rock style and in the end, in Fancy-Pants' frustration, he resorts to using the throwaway suggestion from Dewey to use their school uniforms (with some modifications to suggest a rock-themed school outfit).